# Embedded youtube player in UIWebView is screwing up view hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, ios

I present a UIViewController that has a UIWebView set as its view property in viewDidLoad.
I present this viewcontroller modally from the main screen in my application. The ViewController with the webview is presented in a navigationcontroller which has its navigationbar hidden and its toolbar set with typical browser controls.

All forms of video play fine in the webview except youtube videos.
When the embedded youtube player starts, everything is fine, and the video plays. But when it is exited by pressing the done button, the state of my app jumps back to my home screen while leaving a slither of the webview at the top of the screen, and a slither of a UINavigationController. The UIViewController that contains the UIWebView is never deallocated and continues to exist throughout the time my app is still active.

Here is an image of the problem:
[image]

Here is an image before the youtube player starts:
[image]

The portion at the top is the left over webview with half of a uinavigationcontroller that belongs to the view

I have looked at similar issues here on stack, where other people encounter a similar problem, but they get a crash after a few seconds, because they are modifying a CALayer property. This is not the case here. The app doesn't crash, it just doesn't function properly until I terminate it.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?
Or is there a way to have all youtube videos launch in the youtube app? (though this is less than ideal)

Thanks,
Saam

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got it fixed by now but I have had a similar problem with a navigationcontroller and embedded youtube, and it should work if you are using the newer embed code starting with iframe. That at least worked for me